# Ionic framework 3 - detect 'back' event on previous page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a 'view item list' page and a 'view item details' page. From the 'view item list' page, I am using navCtrl.push('viewItemDetails'). On the item details page, the user may change something, and then hit 'back'.

What I want to do is refresh the 'view item list' page when the user comes back from the details page.

I have tried:

- Using ionViewDidLoad() on the 'list' page - it never fires when the user clicks 'back'.
- Passing in a call back function via navparams which is called from the 'detail' page from the ionViewDidLeave() event. The function executes but all the members are undefined on the 'list' page so it doesn't do what I want.

One option would probably be to use observables on the item list page, but I really would like to do this with lifecycle events if possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 options:

1. Use ModalController instead of NavController, then you know when the modal is dismissed: [ModalController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/).
2. Use [Events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/) in combination with `ionViewDidLeave`.

**Detail page**

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(
    private events: Events,
) {
}

ionViewDidLeave() {
    let data = { id: 123 };
    this.events.publish('list-page:refresh', data);
}
```

**List page**

You can subscribe to the event before doing the push. And unsubscribe after receiving the event data.

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

  constructor(
        private events: Events,
    ) { }

public goToDetail(yourData): void {
    this.events.subscribe('list-page:refresh', (data) => {
        this.yourRefreshMethod(data);
    });
    this.navCtrl.push('your-view', yourData);
}

public yourRefreshMethod(data): void {
    // your code to refresh the page.
    this.events.unsubscribe('list-page:refresh');
}
```

As you can see, before going to the detail page (with params if you wish), it will subscribe to the event for a refresh. When you go into the detail page, when it leaves, it fires the event with any data you want.

After leaving, the event is triggered in the "ListPage", which will call `yourRefreshMethod` with any data you send.

Comment: The detail page was previously a modal but it got too big so I made it a proper page. The event based solution worked great, thank you!